# Finding the error of type I

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

let $x_1.... x_n$ be a  random sample from a Poisson distribution with mean $\theta$, that is

$$f(x ;\theta) = \theta^x e^{-\theta}/x!.$$

We use a test that accepts the null hypothesis if $(1/3)≤ \overline{x} ≤ (2/3)$ and reject otherwise.

For $n=9$ what is the error type I?

My attempt: The idea of this question is to find the region that rejects the null hypothesis when it is true.

$$\begin{align}p(\text{type I error${}\mid H_0$ is true})&=p(\text{reject $H_0$ when $\theta=0.4$})\\
&=p(\overline{x}<(1/3)\mid\theta=0.4)+p(\overline{x}>(2/3)\mid\theta=0.4)\end{align}$$

then I use another idea if $x_i$ with parameter $\theta$ belong to poison then $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)$  is also belong to Poisson with parameter $n\theta$

then I choose $\overline{x}= 0$ and $\overline{x}=1$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for showing what you have done so far.

With your second method, letting $$T = \sum_{i=1}^9 X_i = 9\bar X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(9\theta),$$ you can get an exact Poisson probability:

When $\theta = 0.4,$ you fail to reject $H_0$ if
$3 \le T \le 6,$ so the probability of rejection when $H_0$ is true is
$$1 - P(3 \le T \le 6 \,|\, \lambda = 9\theta = 9(.4) = 3.6)\\ = 1 - P(3 \le T \le 6\,|\,\lambda=3.6) = 0.3760.$$

Using R:

```
1 - sum(dpois(3:6, 3.6))
[1] 0.3760203
```

In the figure below, the rejection regiou
consists of integers outside the vertical
(red) dotted lines.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
t = 0:10;  PDF = dpois(t, 3.6)
plot(t, PDF, type="h", col="blue", lwd=3, main="POIS(3.6)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = c(2.5, 6.5), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

*Note:* Using $\bar X,$ you might try to get the Type I error probability, from a normal approximation, but as you can see from the figure the mean of the underlying Poisson
distribution is not large enough for a
normal approximation to be accurate.

Comment: thank u dear for this explanation, I like how u connect the answer with the R program. And I need suggestions for learning that, any book and link?

Comment: There are various help pages online that are good enough to get you started with R. There are so many procedures in R that no one can possible know them all. So as you start, it is best to learn only the parts of R that are directly relevant to the task at hand. // There are some beginning chapters or appendices in elementary stat and probability books that give quick orientations. You might look on line for ones that you can get for free in PDF form.

Comment: can I contact  u for more details prof